# Highlighting selected view in Listview Android

Tags: android, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a listview and a corresponding listview adapter.

The views displayed in the Listview have I written myself  and it's a framelayout with one button and one imagebutton. The imagebutton is a red cross that deletes the entry and the regular button selects the entry.

When the user presses the regular button, that item is selected and I want to show this to the user by setting the background of that item to green. The application stores which item the user selected and the next time the listview is rendered, THAT item should be selected and green.

Notice that there should be one and EXACTLY one selected item in my listview at all times.

In the getView(.. method in my adaper, it's very easy to change color of the button when the user clicks it. But the button that was green before the user clicked is impossible for me to reference.

- I tried storing a reference the previously selected button, but it never repainted
- I tried removing and adding the data item from the list to trigger notifyDataSetChanged but it never repainted
- I tried setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE), but that led nowhere because I don't know how to catch the choice in my getView  method and paint differently depending on wheter it's selected or not.

All guides I see suggest using notifyDataSetChanged. However, the underlying data is NOT changed in this case and it is not correct (or possible) solution.

So I think that my problem boils down to: HOW can I reference another view in my listview??

(And Yes, I have seen this post: [Highlight selected item in ListView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154358/android-highlight-selected-item-in-listview) . It describes my problem and is answered with "and then change the color of previous selected item's background back to normal" but I still can't refer to the PREVIOUS selected item.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted

Comment: Thanks for the find. However it's the same problem. The selection of the previously selected entry is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Radio Buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html) ? This is exactly the design you need. You can add a "red cross" on each line to delete the line. The selected line is unique and you can iterate on `RadioButton.isChecked();` of your `RadioGroup` to set the background color accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean instead of the imagebutton? (Because I need the functionality for both pressing the cross and outside the cross). If I replace the imagebutton with a radiobutton, it feels like I have the same problem again - the previously pressed radiobutton is in a view I can't reach. (And in the other case I dont get the functioanlity I want)